# Metamask Error: Internal JSON-RPC error. while confirming on metamask mobile

Tags: json, blockchain, metamask, bscscan

We have developed the front end to buy and sell Binance chain tokens. It's working fine on Web Metamask extension when interacting with smart contract. We are using infura API to get connectwallet interface for other wallets on mobile. It's connecting successfully but the transaction is not getting confirmed. Showing this error when I press confirm button, getting Internal JSON-RPC error

[We are getting this issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZIHU.png)

This is the function we are running on confirm:

```
async function change_transfer() {
  if (globalObj.typeTxn == "a") {
    var receiver = payableAmountObjectt.address_to;
  } else {
    var receiver = receiverCoin;
  }

  console.log("receiver", receiver);

  // check address is valid or if not then catch
  await web3Global.utils.toChecksumAddress(receiver);

  if (selectedAccount.toLowerCase() == receiver.toLowerCase()) {
    swal("You cannot transfer to same address").then((value) => {});
    toastr.error("You cannot transfer to same address");
    return false;
  }

  // const balanceOf_ = await web3Global.eth.getBalance(selectedAccount);
  const balanceOf_ = await getBnbBalance(selectedAccount);
  console.log("balanceOf_", balanceOf_);
  var balance_ = 0;
  if (balanceOf_ > 0) {
    balance_ = balanceOf_ / 1e18;
  }
  // console.log(balance_);

  var minBal = 0.001;
  console.log("balance : ", balance_);
  console.log("min balance : ", minBal);

  if (balance_ < minBal) {
    swal(
      "Balance Low",
      "You must have BNB " + minBal + " for transaction."
    ).then((value) => {});
    return false;
  }

  // Get connected chain id from Ethereum node
  const chainId = await web3Global.eth.getChainId();
  // Load chain information over an HTTP API
  const chainData = evmChains.getChain(chainId);
  console.log("chainData = ", chainData.name);
  console.log("chainData = ", chainData);

  var network = chainData.networkId;
  console.log(network);
  payableAmountObjectt.network = network;
  if (checkNetwork(network) == false) {
    return false;
  }

  const contract = new web3Global.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress);

  // var weiAmount = payableAmountObjectt.coin_amount * 1e9;
  var weiAmount = payableAmountObjectt.coin_amount * decimalVal;  var weiAmount2 = weiAmount;
  var value = weiAmount2;
  value = toFixed(value);

  payableAmountObjectt.coin_amount_raw = value;
  var from_account = selectedAccount;

  const balanceOf = await contract.methods.balanceOf(from_account).call();
  console.log("value", value);
  console.log("balanceOf", balanceOf);
  if (value > balanceOf) {
    swal("Balance Low", "Your Token balance is low.").then((value) => {});
    toastr.error("Your Token balance is low.");
    return false;
  }

  payableAmountObjectt.from_address = from_account;
  payableAmountObjectt.to_address = receiver;

  console.log("from_account", from_account);
  console.log("receiver", receiver);
  console.log("value", value);
  $(".payBtn").hide();
  $(".payBtn").attr("disabled", true);
  $("#showLoaderAjaxWeb3Modal").show();

  var gasPrice_gwei = "10";

  var estimateGasRaw = await contract.methods
    .transfer(receiver, value.toString())
    .estimateGas({
      from: from_account,
      gasPrice: await web3Global.utils.toHex(
        web3Global.utils.toWei(gasPrice_gwei, "gwei")
      ),
    });

  var estimateGas = estimateGasRaw;
  console.log("estimateGas", estimateGas);

  const transfer = await contract.methods
    .transfer(receiver, value.toString())
    .send({
      from: from_account,
      gas: await web3Global.utils.toHex(estimateGas), // Raise the gas limit to a much higher amount
      gasLimit: await web3Global.utils.toHex(800000), // Raise the gas limit to a much higher amount
      gasPrice: await web3Global.utils.toHex(
        web3Global.utils.toWei(gasPrice_gwei, "gwei")
      ),

      value: "0x0",
    })
    .on("transactionHash", function (hash) {
      console.log("transactionHash", hash);
      $("#showLoaderAjaxWeb3Modal").hide();
      toastr.success(hash);
      payableAmountObjectt.hash = hash;
      if (payableAmountObjectt.type == "admin") {
        transferTokenUpdate(hash);
      } else {
        transferTokenUpdate_purchase(hash);
      }
    })
    .on("receipt", function (receipt) {
      console.log("receipt", receipt);
    })
    .on("confirmation", function (confirmationNumber, receipt) {
      console.log("confirmation", confirmationNumber, receipt);
    })
    .on("error", function (error, receipt) {
      console.log("error", error, receipt);
      console.log("error.message", error.message);
      console_(error.message, "status");
      toastr.info(error.message);

      if (
        error.message == "User rejected the transaction" ||
        error.message ==
          "MetaMask Tx Signature: User denied transaction signature."
      ) {
        $(".payBtn").show();
        $(".payBtn").attr("disabled", false);
        $("#showLoaderAjaxWeb3Modal").hide();
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, you should look up if the transaction that are you trying to send it valid or not, because in my case Metamask always reverted my transaction because was not valid (contract ownership matter) and throw the "JSON-RPC" error
In your case you should look if you have founds or if are something on the contract that revert your tx so Metamask is throwinh the error